# Merging multiple dlls into single dll in a wpf application

Tags: wpf, dll, merge

I am looking for the solution for merging multiple dlls into a single dll for a wpf application. Is there an utility or some way to do this?

I already checked with ilmerge and costura fody where ilmerge don't support wpf dlls and costura embed dlls into an exe not into dll.

Comment: "costura embed dlls into an exe not into dll"? A WPF application is an .exe...

Comment: Yes did tried with costura fody to embed wpf dlls into exe but was not able to consume/unpack dlls from exe if you can help in this post